# Hey i have a question i want to install bcm

Tags: python

when im trying to install it this error shows up:
Running setup.py clean for pythonnet
Failed to build numpy pythonnet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Can you share the complete error message as well as information about your perating system and python version? Please add them by using the [edit] function

Comment: What is the command to install it ? I tried to install it with "pip install bcm" and it seems to works.